# XNA Texture Size Ratio Optimization

Tags: c#, memory, xna, textures, gpu

Does drawing a **4096x4096** sized texture have an speed/optimization advantage over drawing a **64x4096** sized texture in XNA?

I remember reading somewhere that XNA takes the textures that have a rectangular size ratio and turns them to square ratio textures (equal length and width) before sending them to the GPU and this causes the texture to load slower to GPU memory and more memory is consumed on the GPU. Is this true?